# Finding the Depth-First Index of a Child Given the Parent's Depth First Index Index in Complete k-ary Tree

Tags: trees

I have a complete k-ary tree with a depth of $d$. If I'm given a node's depth-first index, I'd like a closed-form formula for calculating both the nodes children's depth-first indexes along with a formula for calculating the node's depth.

It's possible I just haven't searched the correct terms, but I was only able to find the following blog post on the topic: https://research.swtch.com/treenum